# "npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near.."; cache clean doesn't work

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to get "npm install" working since 2-days now. Answer for almost every other similar question on forum says, "npm cahce clean -f" solves issue.

But, for me it's not working in both cases - 1. for installing new packages globally, 2. for installing local packages for existing project

I have tried using both alternative registry ( https://registry.npmjs.org/ &  http://registry.npmjs.org/). And I'm not behind any proxy also.

I am using -
Windows 7 Ultimate,
Node version: 10.14.1,
NPM version: 6.4.1

I have tried to downgrade to use Node 8.x too. But, doesn't work with that too.

Package.json in my project

```
 {
      "name": "my-ng-app",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "main": "main.js",
      "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve",
        "build": "ng build",
        "test": "ng test",
        "lint": "ng lint",
        "e2e": "ng e2e",
        "electron": "ng build && electron .",
        "electron-aot": "ng build --prod && electron .",
        "electron-packager-windows": "electron-packager . MyNgElectron --platform=win32"
      },
      "private": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "~7.0.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "core-js": "^2.5.4",
        "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
        "sequelize": "^4.41.0",
        "sqlite3": "^4.0.3",
        "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.10.0",
        "@angular/cli": "~7.0.2",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "~7.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
        "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
        "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
        "electron": "^3.0.5",
        "electron-packager": "^12.2.0",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
        "karma": "~3.0.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.4.0",
        "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
        "tslint": "~5.11.0",
        "typescript": "~3.1.1"
      }
    }
```

On the other hand, here is the snapshot of error while installing packages globally...

[image: error while npm package install globally]

Comment: Show your package.json

Comment: @alexmac - I have updated question with my project's package.json. Also note, I'm getting this error for installing packages globally as well.

Comment: Your package.json looks fine. If you have npm-shrinkwrap.json or package-lock.json filers, try remove them. If it won't help, remove node_modules folder completely, clean cache and install dependencies again.

Comment: @alexmac - I had package-lock.json, and after reading other answers I tried after deleting it too along with local node-modules folder, npm-cache folder from AppData\Roaming\. I didn't had npm-shrinkwrap.json though. For more information, I have updated question with screenshot of error while installing packages globally.